# Ruby Regexp match matching repetitive values

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm facing some issues with Ruby Regexp match.

I have the following query and I'd like to scan my parameters:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'exec dbo.MyProcedure @UserID=@p0,@Products=@p1,@CountryCodes=@p2'
    , N'@p0 int,@p1 nvarchar(max) ,@p2 nvarchar(max)'
    , @p0 = 123569
    , @p1 = N'1633,1634'
    , @p2 = N'39A,CS,DE,ES,FR,GB,IT,NL,AB,BS,BU,CR,ET,FI,HU,LA,LT,MD,ME,MV,PL,RO,RS,SK,SV,GR,PT,TR,AT,CH,LI,GG,KS,UK,GI,MN,RR,CY,MT,BL,RU,DK,NO,SE,BE,IC,IE,LX'
```

I've just formatted query to look neat and readable. In my source there are fewer tabs and whitespaces.

Ideally, I'd like to get three matches:

```
@p0 = 123569
@p1 = N'1633,1634'
@p2 = N'39A,CS,DE,ES,FR,GB,IT,NL,AB,BS,BU,CR,ET,FI,HU,LA,LT,MD,ME,MV,PL,RO,RS,SK,SV,GR,PT,TR,AT,CH,LI,GG,KS,UK,GI,MN,RR,CY,MT,BL,RU,DK,NO,SE,BE,IC,IE,LX'
```

However, my Regexp pattern merges @p1 and @p2 and this is what I get:

```
@p0 = 123569
@p1 = N'1633,1634',@p2 = N'39A,CS,DE,ES,FR,GB,IT,NL,AB,BS,BU,CR,ET,FI,HU,LA,LT,MD,ME,MV,PL,RO,RS,SK,SV,GR,PT,TR,AT,CH,LI,GG,KS,UK,GI,MN,RR,CY,MT,BL,RU,DK,NO,SE,BE,IC,IE,LX'
```

I can see where's the issue, however I'm quite new to Regexp and I cannot figure out how to write it properly. This is my expression:

```
(\@p[0-9]+)+\=(\N\'.*\'|[0-9]+|NULL)
```

I'm testing my Regex expression here: http://rubular.com/r/OF5EVD5Nau

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You main problem is the `.*` part in the second alternation, by default regex are greedy and match as much as possible.

You can turn it into lazy or ungreedy by adding a `?` after the repetition operator.

So with little change this would do:

```
(@p[0-9]+)\s+=\s+(\d+|N'.+?'$|NULL)
```

[Rubular example](http://rubular.com/r/SXizep0keU)

There's some unknown from you description on the spaces, I used `+` as repetition operator assuming there will be at least 1 present around the `=` sign, as in the single quotes, I assume they are never empty. Replace by `*` if they are optionnal.

Comment: I've just realized that I have pasted wrong URL. However that seems to be exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: I've updated my answer with correct link now. I've done a slight modification in your expression and removed `$` character (my whole text is in whole line) and it seems to work fine. That's the one: `(@p[0-9]+)=(\d+|N'.+?'|NULL)`. Thanks once more

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas that was one of my concerns when seeing your examples along your regex :p I assume we can left it as-is now, glad it helped :)